# Auth gsutil as service account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We are using Google Cloud Storage from App Engine and need to apply some ACL adjustments to 20.000+ objects. We'd like to use gsutil as it seems to be made for a use case like this.

Unfortunately, for whatever strange reason, objects created by App Engine using the service account are not owned by any of the other owners of the bucket. Hence gsutil fails.

How can we auth gsutil as the service account to make use of its bulk change features?

Google Support doesn't have an answer... Anybody here?

This has been such a frustrating experience that we think of moving this part over to S3 where apps don't exclude human owners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever a new object is created in a bucket, the account that creates it is the owner of the object. Each new object also contains an ACL, which defaults to the "default object ACL" setting on the bucket. By default, this is the "project-private" ACL, which means that any user who is an owner or an editor of the project should have full control of the object and be able to change the ACL with their own credentials.

A couple of things could have happened here. Either the service account, when creating objects, has been explicitly specifying an ACL for each object, or the default object ACL setting on the bucket has been changed to something other than project-private. Have you explicitly tried to lock down these objects to something beyond project-private? If not, make sure that the user account you've configured gsutil with is an owner of the project that you're trying to edit object ACLs with. Can you see what the ACL is from the console (http://console.developers.google.com/storage)?

You cannot act as the appengine project's service account from your own desktop. Fortunately, you CAN act as that service account from a GCE instance. One way to get out of this problem would be to launch a small GCE instance associated with this project. That GCE instance will have a gsutil installed that will be pre-configured to act as the service account. You can simply type `gsutil -m acl set -R project-private gs://my-bucket/` from the GCE prompt (or whatever ACL change you want to make), and it should fix your problem.

Comment: As a side note, the objects created by AppEngine are owned by the service account to avoid issues when developers join or leave a project.  By making the service account own the objects, they are effectively owned by the project as a whole and not any one person working on the project.

Comment: Worked perfectly well, thanks Brandon! I had to manually re-auth but could then act as the App Engine service account.

Answer (score 0):

gsutil can be run as a service account from the desktop as well since version 3.26 according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15646928/3621331

Use "gsutil config -e" to configure it using service account credentials and key that can be created in the Developer Console's "APIs & auth" / "Credentials section".
I couldn't make it work on Windows 7, most likely due to the installed pycrypto, but it worked just fine on Ubuntu.