# Google Storage not using service account even with environment variable properly set

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I was trying to save two files to GCP Storage using the following commands in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
!gsutil cp ./dist/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz gs://$BUCKET_NAME/custom_prediction_routine_tutorial/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz
!gsutil cp model.h5 preprocessor.pkl gs://$BUCKET_NAME/custom_prediction_routine_tutorial/model/
```

The bucket has been created properly since I can see it in the bucket list on GCP. Also in Permissions for the bucket, I can see the service account created. Plus, I made sure the environment variable is set by running:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/george/Documents/Credentials/prediction-routine-new-b7a445077e61.json"
```

This can be verified by running this in Python:

```
import os

print('Credendtials from environ: {}'.format(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')))
```

which shows:

```
Credentials from environ: /home/george/Documents/Credentials/prediction-routine-new-b7a445077e61.json
```

And I do have the json file stored at the specified location. However, when I tried to save files using the commands shown at the top, I kept getting this error message:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 george***@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
Copying file://model.h5 [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 george***@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

So the question is, how come Google Storage is not using my service account and keeps using my user account?

---

**UPDATE**

After activating the service account for the project as pointed out by @Hao Z, GCP is using my service account now. However, I do have the permissions set for this service account...

[image: IAM Permissions]

---

**UPDATE 2**

This seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/546

Comment: Do you authenticate the gcloud tool with your account via run command?
gcloud auth activate-service-account \
> --key-file=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}

Comment: Thank you @HaoZ! After doing this, now it's using my service account since it's saying "AccessDeniedException: 403 prediction-routine-new@prediction-routine-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket." However, under IAM permissions, it does say there is a Storage Object Admin role... as shown in the image in my post above. Would you mind providing some further pointers?

Comment: You can re-grant the Storage Object Admin role to your account prediction-routine-new@prediction-routine-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com, or grant the Storage Object Create and Storage Object Viewer roles to this account. I suggest you use [Policy Troubleshooter](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access#troubleshooting_access) to examine all Cloud IAM policies that apply to the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this in the following steps:

First, Using the way suggested by @Hao Z above, I was able to activate the service account in Jupyter Notebook using:

```
!gcloud auth activate-service-account \
  prediction-routine-new@prediction-routine-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
          --key-file=/home/george/Documents/Credentials/prediction-routine-new-b7a445077e61.json \
          --project=prediction-routine-test
```

Second, I changed the bucket name used after realizing that I was using the wrong name - it should be "prediction-routine" instead of "prediction-routine-bucket".

```
BUCKET_NAME="prediction-routine"
```

Third, I changed the role from "Storage Object Admmin" to "Storage Admin" for the service account's permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Check [How to use Service Accounts with gsutil, for uploading to CS + BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433639/how-to-use-service-accounts-with-gsutil-for-uploading-to-cs-bigquery)

Relevant bit:

```
Download service account key file, and put it in e.g. /etc/backup-account.json
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /etc/backup-account.json
```

Or you can do gsutil -i to impersonate a service account. Use 'gsutil help creds' for more info. I guess the env variable is just used by the Python SDK and not by the CLI.